# Wireless internet doesn't work Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ae]

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I am really new to Ubuntu. My wifi doesn't work, but my wired works. I'm dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 with win 8.1 on a laptop. I cant see any wifi and i think its because i havent install the driver
Pilot6 command:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ae] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0622]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3812]
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Wireless network doesnt show up? It shows up but you can't connect? You can connect but there is no internet? Be a little more specific please.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Is it a Lenovo Edge E555? See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1432869

Answer (score 2):

This device is not supported by the proprietary Broadcom driver `bcmwl-kernel-source` form Ubuntu repository.

You can try the latest Broadcom driver that can be installed by

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

If this driver still does not support your adapter, then there is no way to get it work now.

Comment: aww man, i installed that one, still the same...

Comment: The problem is my ethernet cable is far away from my room and its only in like a really small table and in that table, there is a printer :(

Comment: You can replace the wireless adapter or use a USB dongle.

Comment: whats a usb dongle?

Comment: It is an external Wi-Fi adapter.